# Tensorflow Dataset Mask Sequence for Evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

#### Problem:

Given variable-length inputs, the accuracy metric is incorrect because short vectors are padded to longer ones.

Using the `Masking` layer from `keras` solves this, by applying a mask to all zero values, but because my sequence contains zeros naturally, and super long (50,000 tokens) this slows down training by 50 times!

#### Details

I have a dataset represented in `tf.data.Dataset` which contains 3 properties per example:

1. `src` - an input sequence
2. `tgt` - class ID output sequence
3. `tokens` number of tokens in the sequence

And I would like to train a sequence tagging model.

In order to use it with Keras, I understand I need to only have an `x` and `y` in my dataset, so I map:

```py
dataset = dataset.map(lambda d: (d['src'], d['tgt']))
```

And I pass to a keras model:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),
  tf.keras.layers.Activation(activations.softmax)
])
```

Is there a way to apply a mask as part of the dataset pipeline, in graph mode? (the mask is `tf.sequence_mask(datum['tokens'])`)

#### Alternative solution

Alternatively, there is no issue with passing an unmasked sequence, if I could pass in my dataset the number of `tokens` as well, and create my own evaluation metric that applies the mask there.

I couldn't find how to pass a dataset with 3 items rather than 2, keras sequential model doesn't seem to allow that.

Comment: why not use something else than the sequential model then?

Comment: @NicolasGervais please suggest what to use in this case, then, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: functional api, subclassing api...

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying for an hour without any much progress. Could you please detail it in an answer as an exammple?

Comment: I can paste a fully functioning model with multiple inputs on a toy dataset if it can help you. You can then tune it to your preference

Comment: Please do, if it uses tf datasets, that might help

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. You can see it takes not just input/output, but a second input as well. I'm also using more than 1 output, and so you can pass information in and out of the neural network. I hope you'll feel energized by the customizable nature of this example.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from functools import partial
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
iris, target = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

X = iris[:, :3]
y = iris[:, 3]
z = target

onehot = partial(tf.one_hot, depth=3)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y, z)).shuffle(150)

train_ds = dataset.take(120).shuffle(10).\
    batch(8).map(lambda a, b, c: (a, b, onehot(c)))

test_ds = dataset.skip(120).take(30).shuffle(10).\
    batch(8).map(lambda a, b, c: (a, b, onehot(c)))

next(iter(train_ds))

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.d0 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
        self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.d2 = Dense(1)
        self.d3 = Dense(3)

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.d0(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        a = self.d2(x)
        b = self.d3(x)
        return a, b

model = MyModel()

loss_obj_reg = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
loss_obj_cat = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)

loss_reg_train = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='regression loss')
loss_cat_train = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='categorical loss')

loss_reg_test = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='regression loss')
loss_cat_test = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='categorical loss')

train_acc = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
test_acc = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()


@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, y_reg, y_cat):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        pred_reg, pred_cat = model(inputs, training=True)
        reg_loss = loss_obj_reg(y_reg, pred_reg)
        cat_loss = loss_obj_cat(y_cat, pred_cat)

    gradients = tape.gradient([reg_loss, cat_loss], model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    loss_reg_train(reg_loss)
    loss_cat_train(cat_loss)

    train_acc(y_cat, pred_cat)


@tf.function
def test_step(inputs, y_reg, y_cat):
    pred_reg, pred_cat = model(inputs, training=False)
    reg_loss = loss_obj_reg(y_reg, pred_reg)
    cat_loss = loss_obj_cat(y_cat, pred_cat)

    loss_reg_test(reg_loss)
    loss_cat_test(cat_loss)

    test_acc(y_cat, pred_cat)


for epoch in range(250):

    loss_reg_train.reset_states()
    loss_cat_train.reset_states()

    loss_reg_test.reset_states()
    loss_cat_test.reset_states()

    train_acc.reset_states()
    test_acc.reset_states()

    for xx, yy, zz in train_ds:
        train_step(xx, yy, zz)

    for xx, yy, zz in test_ds:
        test_step(xx, yy, zz)

    template = 'Epoch {:3} ' \
               'MAE {:5.3f} TMAE {:5.3f} ' \
              'Entr {:5.3f} TEntr {:5.3f} ' \
               'Acc {:7.2%} TAcc {:7.2%}'

    print(template.format(epoch+1,
                        loss_reg_train.result(),
                        loss_reg_test.result(),
                        loss_cat_train.result(),
                        loss_cat_test.result(),
                        train_acc.result(),
                        test_acc.result()))
```

Let me know if you need any kind of information.